# grep array parameter of excluded files

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to exclude some files from my `grep` command, for this I'm using parameter:

```
--exclude=excluded_file.ext
```

To make more easy to read I want to use a bash array with excluded files:

```
EXCLUDED_FILES=("excluded_file.ext")
```

Then pass ${EXCLUDED_FILES} array to `grep`, like:

```
grep -Rni "my text" --exclude=${EXCLUDED_FILES}
```

How I can pass an array as parameter to `grep` command?

Comment: either use glob expression, or make a patch on grep.

Comment: I unsuccessfully tried to use `exclude-from` and create a file on the fly: `grep ... --exclude-from="$(<(printf "%s\n" "${excluded_files[@]}"))"`

Comment: @fedorqui You are trying to execute the process substitution's file name as a command. Drop the `$(...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
grep -Rni "${excluded_files[@]/#/--exclude=}" "my text"
```

The parameter expansion `"${excluded_files[@]/#/--exclude=}"` will expand to the expansion of the array `excluded_files` with each field prefixed with `--exclude=`. Look:

```
$ excluded_files=( '*.txt' '*.stuff' )
$ printf '%s\n' "${excluded_files[@]/#/--exclude=}"
--exclude=*.txt
--exclude=*.stuff
```

Comment: Nicely done; because you don't often see it, it's easy to forget that such parameter expansions also work with _arrays_.

Comment: Nicely done. Please explain what means ${excluded_files[@]/#/--exclude=} ?  "/#/" is something like foreach ?

Comment: @daniftodi: the expansion `${array[@]/pattern/replacement}"` is that of `"${array[@]}"` where the first occurence of `pattern` is replaced by `replacement` is each field of the array `array`. The `#` symbol in the pattern is the anchor for the beginning of the string. Similarly, `%` is the anchor for the end of the string.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Variables are not passed to programs as arguments; *values* are. Variables (especially arrays) are expanded by the shell into one or more words, and each *word* is passed as a separate argument to a program. In this specific case, the `--exclude` option takes a single file name as its argument, so you need to build up multiple `--exclude=foo` arguments from your array. One option:

```
for f in "${EXCLUDED_FILES[@]}"; do
    opts+=( --exclude="$f" )
done
grep -Rni "my text" "${opts[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU `grep` also supports the `--exclude-from` option, which takes a *filename* as its argument, with the referenced files containing the patterns to exclude, each on its own line.

If you're not worried about filenames with embedded newlines (rarely a concern), you can use a process substitution as follows to create such a file on the fly:

```
grep -Rni "my text" --exclude-from=<(printf '%s\n' "${EXCLUDED_FILES[@]}")
```

---

As an aside: is It better not to use all-uppercase shell-variable names in order to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

Answer (score 2):

The GNU guys really screwed up when they gave `grep` options for `find`ing files. What's next - options to `sort` it's output or `tr`anslate characters or print just the `head`/`tail` of the results? The UNIX tool for finding files has the very apt and obvious name `find`. The UNIX tool `grep` is also aptly named to "**G**lobally match a **R**egular **E**xpression in a file and **P**rint the result".

So `find` finds files while `grep` prints strings from within files that match a regexp - 2 very different purposes and you should just use the right tool for each job as the UNIX designers intended:

```
findsarg=()
for f in "${EXCLUDED_FILES[@]}"
do
    findsarg+=( '!' -name "$f" )
done
find . -type f "${findsarg[@]}" -exec grep -Hni "my text" {} +
```

Thanks to @gniourf_gniourf for help getting the syntax right for handling file names containing globbing metacharacters and white space.

As mentioned elsewhere though - don't use all upper case names for non-exported variables by convention and to avoid clashing with exported/standard names.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot literally pass an array as a parameter to any command.  All parameters are strings.

You can, however, convert your array to a string containing all the array elements, separated by a delimiter (one space character by default).  The syntax would be

```
grep -Rni "my text" --exclude="${EXCLUDED_FILES[*]}"
```

I should point out, however, that the `--exclude` argument to GNU `grep` does not work that way.  Its value is taken as a *single* glob with which to filter results.  This differs from the `--exclude-from` argument's behavior of treating each line of the file as a separate glob.  If you want to specify multiple exclusion globs on the command line then you'll need to give an `--exclude` argument separately for each one.